# Customized paypal login process

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have used PayPal API to charge a user's credit card.

Does PayPal provide any API to build a customized login screen that I can integrate into my website? I don't want a user to leave my website during the PayPal login process.

Normally, a user is redirected to paypal website to log into the PayPal for payment process if REST api is not used. Is there any API to keep a user on my website for login process?

Comment: Hi - What you're looking for is the seamless checkout flow with PayPal that loads a .js modal like here: https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/navigation?merchant=paypalBt&page=shoppingCart. Click the PayPal button to experience the flow and you can get the code sample there as well. Note, you do not have to use REST to invoke this flow. You can use the standard NVP api's as well. It's in their documentation at paypal developer portal, at very bottom; ALL DOCS link, express checkout in-context

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDT Instead of using IPN,

PDT has a major weakness: it sends order confirmations once and only once. As a result, when PDT sends a confirmation, your site must be running; otherwise, it will never receive the message.

With IPN, in contrast, delivery of order confirmations is virtually guaranteed since IPN resends a confirmation until your site acknowledges receipt. For this reason, PayPal recommends that you implement IPN rather than PDT.

Please find the details in for PDT in the below links,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/

PDT will send the data to your URL as query strings, You can parse and manipulate it.